# Logging a registered user's actions

Tags: python, logging

While logging i need to log only

```
if user_authenticated():
    log.info(msg)
else:
    pass
```

so wondering whether should i do that if then logic every time or make a function
which is preferred way to do that and why?

Comment: One major benefit of wrapping this a function: Say you deploy your code, and set log level to `WARN`, and then discover that you’re spending too much time calling `user_authenticated()`. With a wrapper, you can fix that in 1 line: make the wrapper check the log level first. With 100 copies of be code, you have to fix it in 100 places (or profile and fix it in the 3 most important places but leave it different in 97 other places).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of thumb is: ["if a chunk of code is repeated 3 times, make a function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming)).

E.g. the most straightforward way is to subclass `Logger` so that the overridden `Logger.log()` would check that:

```
def AuthenticatedUserLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(<...>):
        self.is_authenticated = <the facility to call, with enough context
                                to call it from anywhere>
    def log(lvl, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_authenticated():
             super(AuthenticatedUserLogger,self).log(lvl, msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

Alternatively, you can use a `Filter` or a `LoggerAdapter` as per [Python Logging: Group logs which belong to one request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454564/python-logging-group-logs-which-belong-to-one-request/28772910#28772910) .

---

That said, logging like this is probably not the best idea. The purpose of logging is to trace your program's activity so that you know what's happening, or was happening when an error or something else of interest occurred. There is no difference in application logic between authenticated and unauthenticated users here (if there was, you would only hit the `log.info()` line in one of these cases), so why not just use `None` instead of a user name in the latter case?

If you need to track a user's actions, you shouldn't use raw `logging` for that 'cuz it's not what it's designed for: logging points do not necessarity coincide with tracking points. You *can* reuse `logging` machinery for that, but will need to make sure that these two activities do not interfere with each other. E.g. use a dedicated logging level and a filtered `Handler` for telemetry:

```
TELEMETRY_LOGLEVEL = 25
logging.addLevelName(TELEMETRY_LOGLEVEL,'TELEMETRY')

class TelemetryHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(<...>):
        <connect to DB>
    def close():
        <disconnect from DB>
    def emit(record):
        <write to DB>

class TelemetryFilter(logging.filter):
    def filter(record):
        return record.level == TELEMETRY_LOGLEVEL

l = logging.getLogger()
h = TelemetryHandler(<...>)
h.addFilter(TelemetryFilter())
l.addHandler(h)
```

Answer (score 5):

One thing you could do is remove the `else` statement. Indeed, in Python `else` statements are not mandatory to a parent `if` statement. So,

```
if user_authenticated():
    log.info(msg)
```

is entirely equivalent to your code.

Now, if you're going to repeat this code over and over, creating a `logging` method is probably a good idea. Note that this apply for any statements that you would possibly often repeat in your code.