# Python having all logging calls inherit a module name

Tags: python, oop, logging

If this question has been asked before, I am having a hard time finding it. I am building a series of interrelated applications. I have base classes defined in a file, and subclasses are defined elsewhere in another.

```
# base.py
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
class Base():
  def __init__(self):
    logger.info("Parent success")

# class.py
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
class Child(Base):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    logger.info("Child success")

# main.py
this = Child()
```

However, I want all the logging to display the module that calls the classes, so I want both the messages child and parent to show that it's actually being called by main.py. This is because  there are many modules running concurrently that implement and do something with child and base classes.

Is there an elegant solution to this other than passing loggers around objects as an **init** variable? I really dislike this design pattern and was hoping there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can use a different logger name other than `__name__`. Maybe you can just use a single logger for the entire app.

Comment: You could make an abstract base class (https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) that uses `logging` and have each of your classes implement it with messages unique to that class.

Comment: The issue with both of these is that we have to pass our logger object to our object instantiations and accept it as an input in __init__ which is a design pattern I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the easiest way is to use a different name for loggers than `__name__`.

If you really want it to have the name of the object creator's module, you can detect it in your class' constructor with [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html):

```
class Base:
  def __init__(self):
    # Will break in alternate Python implementation
    # that don't implement/emulate live Python execution stack
    caller_module_name = inspect.stack()[1].frame.f_globals['__name__']
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(caller_module_name)
```

---

However, as others have also pointed out, that's not very useful: to troubleshoot problems (the primary use case of logs), you're primarily interested in where each message comes from -- and fake module names complicate that task unnecessarily.

---

What you probably actually want is to add some additional *contextual information* to your log messages (which may include the specific object's "owner module" for whatever reason). For that, see e.g. [Python Logging: Group logs which belong to one request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454564/python-logging-group-logs-which-belong-to-one-request/28772910#28772910).